# Copy to clipboard in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, clipboard

Is there a way at all of altering the clipboard of the user via JavaScript?

I want it that they click a given point on a map, and it adds the coordinates of the position to their clipboard.

I do however assume that this is not possible for JavaScript to achieve.

Comment: Yes it is possible and without any library at all. Take a look at this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46041831/copy-to-clipboard-with-break-line/50230647#50230647

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could try using the [zeroclipboard](http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/) library, which involves placing an invisible flash element on the page to do the actual copy of text to the clipboard.

Answer (score 2):

It is in Internet Explorer, but not in other browsers although support can be [hacked together](http://www.webtips.co.in/javascript/copy-to-clipboard-with-javascript-on-mozilla-firefox-and-ie.aspx) in other browsers by inserting a [Flash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flash) file each time you want to do a copy. Not very useful I would say, as it [imposes usability drawbacks as well](http://www.rodsdot.com/ee/cross_browser_clipboard_copy_with_pop_over_message.asp).

Comment: It's not possible anymore in flash10, as it's a major security flow.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly it is possible in the Internet Explorer (maybe the site must be in the "trusted" zone) but not in Firefox or Opera.